# Magento 2: Extend from rewritten block

Tags: magento2, overrides, extend, preference

Originally: There are 2 blocks like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module_1\Block;
class ParentBlock{}
class ChildBlock extends ParentBlock {}
```

Now, I need to rewrite ParentBlock using di.xml:

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module_1\Block\ParentBlock" type="Vendor\Module_2\Block\ParentBlock" />

namespace Vendor\Module_2\Block;
class ParentBlock extends \Vendor\Module_1\Block\ParentBlock {}
```

How can I make **\Vendor\Module_1\Block\ChildBlock** extend from **\Vendor\Module_2\Block\ParentBlock**?

If there is any more information needed, please tell me.

Thanks in advanced.

===

**Updated** following answers from @Raphael at Digital Pianism.

Thanks for your explanation. And I thought as you said too, but in my case, it doesn't work.

I have to create a new preference for Module_1\ChildBlock. Then I have to create new Module_2\ChildBlock like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module_2\Block;
class ChildBlock extends \Vendor\Module_2\Block\ParentBlock {}
```

Finally, I have to copy all methods from Module_1\ChildBlock to this one.

This is so crazy!!! I don't know what's wrong, as well as how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The preference will do everything you need for you.

A simplified definition of defining preferences for some classes could be that the new classes will be used instead of the old ones.

So in your case, as you defined a preference for the `ParentBlock` class, the `ChildBlock` will automatically extend the new `ParentBlock` class thanks to your preference

To summarize, **everytime Magento 2 is supposed to instantiate `Module_1\ParentBlock` it will actually instantiate `Module_2\ParentBlock` instead**

Comment: Please check my update above and discuss this. I think that there would be the case that the ChildBlock is still actually extended from Module_1\ParentBlock, despite the preference we use.

Comment: @TylerBean there's definitely an issue here. Does Module 2 depends on Module 1 ?

Comment: I have 2 ChildBlock, one of them doesn't override __construct method. Is it the cause?

Comment: @TylerBean I'm not sure to be honest